# Parallax effect on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, parallax

I want to make a parallax effect in android, I've been looking for proposes and I read about accelerometer. If someone knows something or has any idea, please help me. This is my code, but doesn't make the job that I want:

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {
    private var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel? = null

    private var sensorManager: SensorManager? = null
    private var sensorGyr: Sensor? = null

    private var height:Int? = null
    private var width:Int? = null

    private lateinit var viewModel: ProfileViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        initViewModelToActivity()
        parallaxEffect()
    }

    fun initViewModelToActivity(){
        activity?.let {
            sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        }
        val handler = Handler()
        handler.postDelayed({
            sharedViewModel?.ColorBottomNavDefaul?.postValue("Perfil")
        },100)

    }

    fun parallaxEffect(){
        sensorManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager?
        sensorGyr = sensorManager?.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)

        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        activity?.windowManager?.defaultDisplay?.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        height=displayMetrics.heightPixels
        width=displayMetrics.widthPixels

        if (sensorGyr == null)
            Toast.makeText(context, "No tiene el sensor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val mEventListener = object : SensorEventListener {
            override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor, accuracy: Int) {

            }
            override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
                val anim1 = TranslateAnimation(0f, 16f, 0f,0f)
                anim1.duration = 500

                if(event.values[0] > 5) {
                    Log.d("Movement", "+5")
                    anim1.fillAfter = true
                    bg.startAnimation(anim1)
                }
                if(event.values[0] < -5) {
                    Log.d("Movement", "-5")
                    anim1.fillAfter = true
                    anim1.repeatCount = -1
                    anim1.repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE
                    bg.startAnimation(anim1)
                }
            }
        }
        sensorManager?.registerListener(mEventListener,sensorGyr, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Could you explain the problem you're facing? what's "the thing" that does not work?

Comment: I mean, that the code posted doesn't make the effect as I want.

Comment: Do you see that nobody knows whatever you're thinking if you don't specify? Does the code crash? What's it supposed to be doing? Do you know that parallax is also an effect in 2d sidescrolling videogames and this can be missinterpreted? Your question is vague.